Does a break in consciousness mean a death of personhood?
Descartes famously states, "I exist but how often," In this statement, he assumes that in every instance of consciousness, it is him —- the same self —- that exists. If we conceive of consciousness as a continuous stream, it seems reasonable to believe that the self persists from one moment to the next. But this assumption becomes problematic when considering states like dreamless sleep, during which conscious awareness seems to vanish entirely.
Descartes does not explicitly address the question of whether the self persists through these gaps in consciousness. Can we truly be certain that it will be "me" who wakes up after sleep? It seems possible to doubt whether the continuity of self is preserved when consciousness is absent, such as during deep sleep, coma, or severe brain injury.
While some might argue that consciousness persists in a reduced or latent form during dreamless sleep, this "scientific" perspective on consciousness does not necessarily align with the philosophical concept of self-awareness. Even if this reduced state of consciousness exists, it still raises questions about whether the conscious "I" is the same before and after a period of unconsciousness. Thus, it remains a genuine philosophical concern (also keep the cloning problem in mind when answering).

What is so special about sleep? Can we truly be certain that it is the same "me" in the next moment as in the previous one? Maybe it is a new "me" each moment complete with fake memory of past "awareness". If we are trusting memory on that then we might as well trust it after sleeping. If "conceiving" of consciousness as a continuous stream is enough to dispel the doubts we might as well "conceive" of lakes along the way where the streaming stops and then resumes. Or "conceive" some other scenic analogy, with light and blackouts say.

Identity over time is not a well defined concept anyway, does not matter if continuity is broken or not, same as one never jumps in the same river twice.

In psychological terms the process of becoming a person can be disrupted by socialization trauma. I am thinking of feral children and one case report where an evil mother would put the very young girl in a closet, tell her to be quiet, and threaten to cut off her thumbs with a knife. Feral children do not become typical or normal persons in society. The girl who was abused by her mother at home must have been sent to school. As an adult she could work and pay rent. But she had complete amnesia concerning her personal life. She could not recall details of her personal life during psychotherapy.

You ask:

Does a break in consciousness mean a death of personhood?

No. Generally, personhood is often tracked in terms of personal identity (SEP). Therefore, a minor gap in conscious experience in no way fundamentally alters the identity of a person. That is to say, there is continuity of identity even with sleep. The SEP says:

Personal identity deals with philosophical questions that arise about ourselves by virtue of our being people (or as lawyers and philosophers like to say, persons). This contrasts with questions about ourselves that arise by virtue of our being living things, conscious beings, moral agents, or material objects. Many of these questions occur to nearly all of us now and again: What am I? When did I begin? What will happen to me when I die?

Notice that breaks in consciousness, even if extended, do not alter fundamentally the answers to these questions, at least no more than other life-altering experience that have existential import. After an extended coma, one might wake up and reassess one's life, but barring brain damage, one wouldn't come back speaking a different language, remember a false history, or experience life as a fourteenth-century sailor.

To be conscious is a property of certain mental processes.

The conscious processes shutdown during
dreamless sleep and restart
at awakening. The awakening individual experiences himself/herself as
being the same person as before.
So a break of consciousness is
normally not felt as the death of personhood.
But there are some mental disturbances - sometimes due to brain injuries - where an
individuum loses his personhood, e.g., the dissociative phenomenon     of depersonalization.

Self-consciousness and consciousness of the
world around us is the human capability to develop a self-model
embedded within a world-model, see Thomas Metzinger: Being   No One. Both models are implemented as a dynamical mental data structures.
A good introduction from the viewpoint of neuroscience is Christof
Koch: Consciousness.



yes the person that wakes does belive themself to be the person that went to sleep but this isnt confirmation that it isnt a different subjective experience, to further clarify my point id compare the teleporter problem to this situation of wake vs sleep

@askingquestions Please add in your post what you exactly mean by teleportation, discriminating between real experiments and science fiction. And taking into account the no-cloning theorem. Thanks.

im specifically talking about the one presented in "the emperor's new mind" by roger penrose. wich is an hypotetical scenario of course, but either way i believe its relevant

Personal identity, or personhood, is generated via items of recognition in the field of awareness:

Awareness = {items}

If the field of awareness is empty then there are no items of recognition and therefore one cannot identify a source of cause of Awareness.

Awareness = {}

The question evokes these items of recognition including a map or relation to truth values:

Awareness = {disrupted-consciousness, disrupted-personhood, life or death, true or false?}

One can see that a subjective relation must be evaluated forming a relation or map from more fundamental concepts of continuity or disruption, consciousness, personhood, life or death, true or false.
I refer to the cause of Awareness = {items} using the pseudo-scientific concept of Psychogenesis.

Awareness = {Psychogenesis}

This just means we recognize conscious recognition arising as the product of an unknown and mysterious natural process. The mystery must exist because the field of awareness is theoretically empty and one can experience the empty field of awareness via modes of contemplation. Any idea of a source of cause of awareness, however, means the field of awareness is populated with items of recognition.
